# The Matrix form of the Van der Pol equation

Tags: matrices, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, matrix-analysis

Motivated by the [classical Van der Pol equation  which has  a unique periodic attractor,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator) we  consider the following differential equation on $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times M_{2}(\mathbb{R}):$

$$(*)\;\;\;\begin{cases}  X'=Y-(X^{3}-X)\\
Y'=-X\end{cases}$$

> 1. Is there a  periodic attractor for this 8 dimensional dynamical system?
>
> 2.Does $(*)$  have  a  periodic orbit  which  do not enter the  diagonal space $$\{(A,B)\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\mid A, B \;\;\text{are diagonal  matrices }\}$$
>
> 3. Is it true to say that, similar as the classical 2 dimensional case, the infinity of $\mathbb{R}^{8}\simeq M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\times M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is structurally unstable , in the following sense?:

"For every  compact  set $K\subset  \mathbb{R}^{8}$, there  is  a  compact set $\tilde{K}  \supseteq K$ such that  whenever $p \in \tilde{K}^{c}$  we  have  $\phi_{t}(p)\in K^{c},\;\;\forall t \leq 0$."

Here $\phi_{t}$ is the  flow of the corresponding vector field $(*)$.

Comment: Have you run a numerical test and plotted some slices?

Comment: @AHusain  Thanks for your comment. No I did not test. In this question I search for some theoretical methods  which can be  applied for consideration of  a planar polynomial vector field as a vector field on matrix space. May be plotting can help us to find some ideas, but I did not try.

Comment: It's "Van der Pol, not "Vander pol"

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can tell you is that there are invariant manifolds 
$$ \eqalign{x_{21} &= a x_{12} \cr
            y_{21} &= a y_{12} \cr
            x_{11} &= x_{22} = y_{11} = y_{22} = 0\cr} $$
on which the system becomes
$$ \eqalign{y_{12}' &= - x_{12}\cr
            x_{12}' &= x_{12} + y_{12} - a x_{12}^3 \cr}$$
which is similar to the van der Pol system if $a > 0$, but is unstable if $a < 0$.

In particular the answer to (2) is Yes.