# A particular case of of the higher dimensional Poincare Bendixson theorem

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, index-theory

We  consider the planar  polynomial   vector field $$(*) \;\;\;\begin{cases} \dot x= P(x,y) \newline \dot y =Q(x,y)\end{cases}$$

We replace the real variables  $x,y$ with complex variables $x:=x_{1}+ix_{2},\;\;\; y:=y_{1}+iy_{2}$.

This  gives  us a real polynomial vector  field in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. This $4$ dimensional system is denoted by $(*_{C})$

Moreover, in the planar  system $(*)$, [as in the following post,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254235/the-matrix-form-of-the-van-der-pol-equation)  we replace  the real variables $x,y$  with square  matrices  $x,y \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. This gives us  a vector field on $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\times M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ which is  denoted by $(*_{M})$.

> Is there  a planar  polynomial vector field $(*)$ such that the corresponding higher dimensional  system $(*_{C})$ or $(*_{M})$ has a compact invariant set $K$ which does not contain any singular point or periodic orbit?

In the  other  words:

**Is the Poincare Bendixson theorem true for complexification or matrix form of  a polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}?$**

**Note:** I hope that the tag "index theory" I choose for this  question,  is  not inappropriate.  I choose it since I could not find a tag "Conley index". On the other hand this question may be some how related  to methods in Conley index theory.